# Zend Framework Paginator cache doesn't work (no hit)

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I use a file based cache to cache a paginator:

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();

$ret = $table   ->select()
        ->from($table,array('id',
                            'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) as date',
                            'categoryId',
                            'title',
                            'teaser'))
        ->where('`categoryId`=?',$cat)
        ->order('date desc');

$adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($ret);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

$fO = array('lifetime' => 3600, 'automatic_serialization' => true);
$bO = array('cache_dir'=>APPLICATION_PATH . '/cache');
$cache = Zend_cache::factory('Core', 'File', $fO, $bO);
Zend_Paginator::setCache($cache);

$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

Now every request, the paginator creates a neew cache entry and ignors the old one created? Any ideas?

Comment: could it be a permission issue on the cache dir? To test it with `chmod 777` on the cache dir

Comment: No since it creates a new fileon every request. Every file has the same content but different filename (hash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some similar problems with **Zend_Paginator**. These problems only come with **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect** (I had no problems with **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array**).

The bolded part of the cache filename `zend_cache---Zend_Paginator_3_`**2b49905a9282f742e1cefafc53892794** is made by **_getCacheId** function (check **Zend_Paginator**) based on the adapter passed to the constructor. On each request, the paginator creates a new code because the adapter is never the same at the `$_cache->load` moment and `$_cache->save` moment.

The md5 serialized value of the adapter used as filename when data is saved into cache is different from the one used when data is read from cache if you have DB profiler enabled. You must not use DB profiler in order for the **Zend_Paginator** cache to work (use it only in development stage).

Another failure reason that I have found is determined by these two lines of code:

```
$offset = ($pageNumber - 1) * $this->getItemCountPerPage();
$items = $this->_adapter->getItems($offset, $this->getItemCountPerPage());
```

They are called between `$_cache->load` and `$_cache->save` and they add a **limitcount** value and a **limitoffset** value to adapter. This values aren't set when `$_cache->load` is called so the filename based on the md5 serialized value of the adapter will be different in this case too.

They must be placed before `$_cache->load`. You can make a paginator class that extends **Zend_Paginator** and modify **getItemsByPage** function. Add the two lines at the beggining, after `$pageNumber = $this->normalizePageNumber($pageNumber)`.

This worked for me. I hope it will help others too.